# mv all files except their file name ends with .zip

Tags: linux, mv

I'm looking for a `Linux` command to move files from a directory to another, but only if their file name doesn't end with `.zip`.

Is their a command like: `mv ~/Folder1/!*.zip ~/Folder2/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mv $(ls ~/Folder1/ |grep -v "zip$"  ) ~/Folder2/
```

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is `bash` and the option `extglob` is enabled, you can do it like this too

```
mv ~/Folder1/!(*.zip) ~/Folder2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
mv ~/Folder1/!(*.zip) ~/Folder2/
```